# ImportError: cannot import name 'ViT' from 'tensorflow.keras.applications'

Tags: python, tensorflow

how to use Vision Transformer (ViT) models for image classification in tensorflow. I'm unable to import them in my pc with tensorflow (2.4.0) or in Google Colab (tensorflow 2.11) with

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ViT
```

The error bellow accured while executing the code:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ViT' from 'tensorflow.keras.applications'
```

Comment: According to comments in the answer below, this question comes from a incorrect ChatGPT answer, this is an excellent example on why you should  not study or learn coding using ChatGPT, as you might not be aware when the answers are incorrect. Keras documentation does not show any ViT models in keras.applications: https://keras.io/api/applications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViT model is not currently included in the tensorflow.keras.applications module.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But as it's not included yet why ChatGPT is giving examples with it ??

Comment: @BayaLina ChatGPT does not always give correct answers, this is a prime example why you should not ask this kind of stuff to ChatGPT. The Keras documentation does not show any ViT models: https://keras.io/api/applications/

Answer (score 0):

You can import the vision transformer using "from vit_keras import vit"